# Will fruit rot?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I'm stockpiling fruit to sell on another island. Do I have to worry about fruit spoiling/going bad the same way that turnips do? Or is that trait specific to turnips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fruit won't spoil, turnips spoil as part of the price management minigame. They are unique in that regard.